# "no pg_hba.conf entry for host" but "LOG: connection authorized"

Tags: php, postgresql, connection, database-connection, postgresql-9.1

I have a wierd problem. I have a service running using PostgreSQL 8.3. On parallel platform I have installed PostgreSQL 9.1 and try to connect to it using my working php script. Got an answer:

```
pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: 
FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "X.X.X.X", 
user "postgres", database "dbtrsy", SSL off
```

My pg_hba.conf contains:

```
host    all         all         X.X.X.X/32      password
host    all         all         Y.Y.Y.Y/32      password
```

I can easily connect to DB using PgAdmin from Y.Y.Y.Y. Now the wierd thing: I look at the log and I can see:

```
LOG:  connection received: host=X.X.X.X port=55696
LOG:  connection authorized: user=postgres database=dbtrsy
LOG:  disconnection: session time: 0:00:00.017 user=postgres database=dbtrsy host=X.X.X.X port=55696
```

Any clue why I got disconnected automatically after being authorized correctly? When I try to login with different password / username it throw "password authentication failed" error whis is correct.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Just a guess: incompatible client library?

Comment: Hmmm... could be but I don't really believe in it, because I am using standard php library. Info from phpinfo: 

PostgreSQL(libpq) Version 9.1.9
PostgreSQL(libpq) PostgreSQL 9.1.9 on x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.7.2 20120921 (Red Hat 4.7.2-2), 64-bit

Answer (score 0):

If I were to guess, I would guess that something is causing the pg_hba.conf to be read incorrectly, perhaps exposing some sort of bug in the underlying system, or perhaps with another non-bug problem.

My recommendation for a problem of this sort is to take it up on the PostgreSQL email lists, and be prepared to show your entire configuration.  You could also try commenting out lines in the pg_hba.conf until you find the problem.  If your configuration is sufficiently sensitive, you may want to run another server with the same configuration, but different IP addresses on the client, to create a self-contained test case.